# SWFAddress Deeplinks and C# library?

Tags: asp.net, flash

Is there a C# class for interacting with SWFAddress deeplink URL strings (reading deeplink parameters, building SWFAddress URLs, etc.)? Planning to write one myself otherwise; but I wanted to make sure I wasn't reinventing the wheel first.

Comment: Hm what is the platform? How're you going to run c# within browser? Silverlight? Or some C#-to-Flash compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to read those deep linking URLs on the server side (which I assume you are), know that it's not possible.

Those deep linking systems use the fragment part of URLs (the part that comes after the hash (`#`) symbol) for designating specific parts of the flash apps in the browser URL and fragments are not sent to the web server by browsers when making requests -- they're simply meant for browsers to be able to move to a certain part of the page by themselves.

So in order to access full deep linking URLs, you'll have to write a client-side solution (e.g. with Javascript or AS3).