# Accessing deep linking url from ASP.Net Server Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, swfaddress

I'm aware that ASP.Net Request.Url cannot give me [deep linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_linking) url generated by SWFAddress.

http://www.mysite.com/Default.aspx#/6/

ASP.Net Request.Url only returns

http://www.mysite.com/Default.aspx

I found one question but it is quite old - [SWFAddress Deeplinks and C# library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77637/swfaddress-deeplinks-and-c-sharp-library)

Is there any library/technique to access deep linking url from Server Side?

Thanks!

**Updated:** Here is what I get when I access /Default.aspx#/6/

```
? Request.Url
{http://localhost:56476/Default.aspx}
    AbsolutePath: "/Default.aspx"
    AbsoluteUri: "http://localhost:56476/Default.aspx"
    Authority: "localhost:56476"
    DnsSafeHost: "localhost"
    Fragment: ""
    Host: "localhost"
    HostNameType: Dns
    IsAbsoluteUri: true
    IsDefaultPort: false
    IsFile: false
    IsLoopback: true
    IsUnc: false
    LocalPath: "/Default.aspx"
    OriginalString: "http://localhost:56476/Default.aspx"
    PathAndQuery: "/Default.aspx"
    Port: 56476
    Query: ""
    Scheme: "http"
    Segments: {string[2]}
    UserEscaped: false
    UserInfo: ""
```

**Update**: I'm sorry that I did not make my question clear. If user browsers the following url (mostly likely saved in favorite),  I would like to retrieve the full url from server side. You can go to that url; it is a real app.

http://publ.com/Kgd3A5y#/13/zoomed

**My Current Solution:** I subscribe an event (let say page load) at client side. I parse the url at client side, and return to server using ajax. Disadvantage is it creates two page loads.

Comment: possibly a silly question but have you tried looking at the AbsoluteUrl property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of URL with # is anchor. Anchors are only visible on the client side. You need to deal with anchors on client side with for example JavaScript and You can transform Your request to proper URL readable on server side.

This is not Asp.Net or C# specific. It is standard behavior for any server technology.

Just to quote standard [RFC1808](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt):

> **Note that the fragment identifier (and the "#" that precedes it) is not considered part of the URL.**

**Update**:

If You want to send some data from Your swf to server You can write web service on the server side and then swf can communicate with this web service, so You can send whatever data You like.

Client side JavaScript would be fine to send URL to web service as well.

**Edit:**

Mate You got plenty of requests already:

> 81 requests  ❘  1.37MB transferred  ❘  24.10s (onload: 2.41s,
>   DOMContentLoaded: 2.17s)

, so sending few bytes with asynchronous request would not make any difference I think.

Besides I do not think there is much You can do. Anchor is entirely client side thing, it's **NOT** part of the URL, and to deal with it You need to process on the client side and to process on the client side You need to load Your client script from server, end of story.

There is socket communitacion avaliable in Flash, but it's overdo and You mentioned that You have no access to swf code.

Really I can see no reason to change what You have and no good alternative as well.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'm aware of that; my question is how to solve it.

Comment: Yes my application is currently working like that using ajax. But I don't like firing two page loads on initial request.

Comment: You should not fire 2 page loads. You need to load page and send Your data to web service with asynchronous request. This request can fire after page is loaded and in practice You do not need any response  from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this is not deep linking.  You are talking about local anchors.  Something totally different.

Your problem needs to be re-defined and then it can be understood.  You problem is not deep linking.  Your problem is that a local program is generating a local value (anchor) for local work.

If you need this information on the server side (and given our new definition on the surface it would seem you would not -- local work and data expects to be local), then you need to do one of two things.

1. REDEFINE your requirements and design to not perform these functions locally.
2. IMPLEMENT communication between local process and your server to communicate this information.

---

Based on the comment and thinking about this problem:

You can implement a solution easy with the following change to your requirements (#1 above)

Instead of using link that look like this

```
http://www.mysite.com/Default.aspx#/6/
```

Use links that look like this

```
http://www.mysite.com/Default.aspx/6/
```

or

```
http://www.mysite.com/Default.aspx?6/
```

These are actual "deep links" and the server side will be able to see them, your library will also be able to handle them.  (Based on the quick scan of the documentation you linked to.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. SWF address call it as deep linking. I don't know whether it is right or wrong. http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/

Comment: FlippingBook is the third party app and it tightly synchronizes with SWFAddress' deep linking urls (you can see a demo link in my question). My current solution is parse the url at client side, and return to server using ajax. But I don't like firing two page loads on initial request. Thank you for your tip.